# Invalid GeoJSON object loading data from file to React Leaflet using Next.js

Tags: next.js, leaflet, geojson, react-leaflet

I'm working on a small Next.js app using React Leaflet. I previously had my code working using an API route, but for architectural reasons I've needed to switch to using a static GeoJSON file in the short term. The issue I'm running into is that I'm getting a Leaflet error of `Invalid GeoJSON object`. I've tested the GeoJSON on https://geojsonlint.com/ and the points load correctly, so  I have to assume that the error comes from how I'm passing or accessing the data to the Leaflet application or something else potentially framework related.

Logging the console in both the page and component shows my correct GeoJSON,  so I'm really stumped by what I'm doing wrong.

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, GeoJSON } from 'react-leaflet'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
import 'leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility/dist/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility.css'
import 'leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility';

const Map = ({points}) => {

const markerOptions = {radius: 2, weight: 1, opacity: 1, fillOpacity: 0.8, }

const markerStyles = function(feature) {
  switch (feature.properties.art_type) {
      case 'Sticker': return {color: "#800026"};
      case 'Mural':   return {color: "#BD0026"};
      case 'Marker':   return {color: "#E31A1C"};
      case 'Characters':   return {color: "#FC4E2A"};
      case 'Letters':   return {color: "#FD8D3C"};
      case 'Tippex':   return {color: "#FEB24C"};
      case 'Spray':    return {color: "#FED976"}
      }
}
// Map Events
const geoJsonRef = useRef();

const onMouseOut = (e) => {
  var layer = e.target;
  geoJsonRef.current.setStyle(markerOptions);

}

const onMouseOver = (e) => {
  var layer = e.target;

    layer.setStyle({
        weight: 5,
        color: '#666',
        dashArray: '',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    });

    if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
        layer.bringToFront();
    }
}



function onEachFeature(feature, layer){
  if(feature.properties){
    layer.bindPopup("<div class='popupImage'</div><img src=" + "https://d2qr25zh4rluwu.cloudfront.net/" + encodeURI(feature.properties.filename) + ".jpg " + "alt='peng spot photo'" + "height='200px'"  + " " + ">" + "<div>" + "Type:" + feature.properties.art_type + "</div><div>" + "Date Seen: " + feature.properties.timestamp + " </div>")
  }
  layer.on({
      mouseover: onMouseOver,
      mouseout: onMouseOut,
      //click: zoomToFeature
  });
}

function pointToLayer(feature, latLng){
  return L.circleMarker(latLng, markerOptions)
}

return (
    <>
    <MapContainer center={[50.1109, 8.6821]} zoom={14} scrollWheelZoom={false} style={{height: "100%", width: "100%"}} renderer={L.canvas()}>
      <TileLayer
    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    attribution="&copy; <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
  />
     
    <GeoJSON data={points} pointToLayer={pointToLayer} pathOptions={markerStyles} onEachFeature={onEachFeature}  ref={geoJsonRef} />
    </MapContainer>
</>
)
}

export default Map


import Head from 'next/head'
import { useColorMode, Box } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import Container from '../components/Container'
import points from '../data/pengs.json'

export async function getStaticProps(context){
   return{
    props: {
        points,
    }
   }
}

export default function MapPage(props) {
console.log(props.points)
const {colorMode} = useColorMode()
const colorSecondary = {
    light: 'gray.700',
    dark: 'gray.400'
}

const MapWithNoSSR = dynamic(() => import("../components/Map"), {
ssr: false
});

return(
    <>
    <Container>
        <Head> 
            <title>Map</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        </Head>
        <Box
        height={{
            base: '777px',
            sm: '777px',
            md: '1060px',
            lg: '100%',

        }}
        >
        <MapWithNoSSR points={props} />
        </Box>

    </Container>
    </>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was how I was accessing the data, rather than just the `props` variable, I got a step further by accessing it with `props.points`, however I'm still having issues with accessing the data in my application...